# Create image_tag for lower level foldername + stored image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I create an image_tag for a images stored in a lower level of the default assets/images directory? Currently I am storing all of my pictures in the assets/images/pictures folder.

Heres an example. Currently using `@mypic` instance variable with the stored base url:
`pic1.jpg`

.erb file:
`<%= image_tag @mypic.photoUrl %>`

creates an image tag
`<img src="/assets/pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">`

What I want is for the src to be `/assets/images/pictures/pic1.jpg`

OR is ruby on rails convention to put all my heterogeneous images (eg logo, profile pics, arrow pics, landscape pics, button pics) in the image directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick, easy solution would be to just write `<%= image_tag "pictures/#{@mypic.photoUrl}" %>.

Documentation for image_tag [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag).